# How can I add event listener only for THIS object instance

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, instances

I've got a basic jQuery plugin. This plugin can have multiple instances.

The problem: every time new instance is created, a click event will fire in all instances. 
I just want to limit the event to one particular instance. Your answer would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/skrobotov/63kL9Lqg/

```
(function($){

  if(!$.SQ){
      $.SQ = new Object();
  };

  $.SQ.Check = function(options){

    function sayhi() {
      alert('HI');
    };

    this.localhi = new sayhi();

    $( "#PhoneSQNewConnectBtn" ).bind( "click", function() {
      this.localhi = new sayhi();
    });

};

})(jQuery, window, document);

// Create multiple instances
this.generateNewNumber1 = new $.SQ.Check();
this.generateNewNumber2 = new $.SQ.Check();
this.generateNewNumber3 = new $.SQ.Check();
```

Comment: you have 3 click handlers registered to the button... so any click will trigger the handler 3 times

Comment: what is the expected behavior

Comment: That makes sense Arun, I need to move the event handlers outside the plugin, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Arun P Johny mentioned it's not the best idea to put event listeners inside a plugin which gets instantiated.